# add a imageView below existing textview PROGRAMMATICALLY

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

How to add view programmatically to existing view, for example I have textview in XML and now I need to add imageview below that textview programmatically, here is what I tried,

```
     HorizontalScrollView scroll = new HorizontalScrollView(getApplicationContext());
    LinearLayout imageLayout = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
    scroll.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(imageLayout.getWidth(),
            imageLayout.getHeight()));
    scroll.addView(imageLayout);

    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {

        final ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
        imageView.setTag(i);
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.logo);

        imageLayout.addView(imageView);


        imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.e("Tag", "" + imageView.getTag());
            }
        });
    }but its not adding any imageview, I'm trying to do this in **AlertDialog**
```

Comment: Did you add the HorizontalScrollView to the existing View hierarchy? From the snippet, I can see you have created a HorizontalScrollView scroll and added a imageView to that.

Answer (score 0):

`ScrollView` cannot have more than one child. You should wrap your layout inside of a `LinearLayout` and then after you can add any number of views into that `LinearLayout`. cheers :)

Comment: Where exactly are they adding more than one `View` to the `HorizontalScrollView`?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing with wrong way.
Once check with below code snippet.

```
LinearLayout yourlayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layoutid);//Layout which is inside scrollview

    LinearLayout imageLayout = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    // add the rule that places your LinearLayout below your TextView object
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, TextView.getId());

    // set the layoutParams on the LinearLayout
    imageLayout.setLayoutParams(params);


    yourlayout.addView(imageLayout);

    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {

        final ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
        imageView.setTag(i);
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.logo);

        imageLayout.addView(imageView);


        imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.e("Tag", "" + imageView.getTag());
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding

```
<HorizontalScrollView 
android:id="@+id/horizontal_scroll"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    </LinearLayout>

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

in XML

&

```
  LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
    imageView.setId(i);
    imageView.setPadding(2, 2, 2, 2);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
            getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher));
    imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    layout.addView(imageView);
}
```

in MainActivity.java

Answer (score -1):

```
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this.getActivity());
imageView.setId(View.generateViewId());
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, imageView.getId());
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional [context](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) regarding _how_ and/or _why_ it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now! Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43250693/edit) your answer to add an explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. It also doesn't hurt to mention why this answer is more appropriate than others.